# Proper HTTP code when trying to add sub-resource but there's no parent resource

Tags: rest, http

I have two paths:

- `/students`
- `/students/{id}/addresses`

..with the following behavior:

- `POST` to `/students` - `201 Created` (if successfully created a Student)
- `POST` to `/students/{id}/addresses` - `201 Created` (if successfully created the Address under the requested Student)

Now, imagine a situation where I `POST` to `/students/7/addresses`, but there's no `Student` with `id = 7`.
What's the proper HTTP Code in this situation?

Firstly, I thought that it should be `404`, with a response body describing that there's no `Student` with `id = 7`, but I'm not so sure.

What's the best approach in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, imagine a situation where I POST to /students/7/addresses, but there's no Student with id = 7. What's the proper HTTP Code in this situation?

I would expect to see 404 used in this case.

As noted by [Evert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53785319/54734), the "subresource" nature of the target is a red herring; as far as HTTP is concerned, there is no relationship implied by the spellings `/students/7` and `/students/7/addresses`.  They are different resources.

(There is some confusion on this point, because RFC 3986 discusses "hierarchy" in its discussion of [path segments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3), but that really is about the resolution mechanics, and how [dot segments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4) work in relative resolution.  We can choose to align our identifier hierarchy with path segments, but HTTP doesn't make that a requirement, and generic components aren't allowed to assume this is so).

So the POST to `/students/7/addresses` needs to be understood in isolation.  HTTP has semantics very similar to that of a key value store - the target uri of the request is the key that gives you access to the representations.

In your specific case, you have a key that references a resource that doesn't currently exist in the store.  That sounds to me a lot like a [404 Not Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4).

> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

The body of the response would normally include additional information about what's going on, but we probably want generic HTTP components to treat this as they would a spelling error in the URL.

Michael Kropat's [Stop Making It Hard](https://www.codetinkerer.com/2015/12/04/choosing-an-http-status-code.html) has a useful decision tree for questions about status codes.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP doesn't really know about hierarchy. There's no concept of parent and sub-resources. We (as API developers) add this concept.

However, there is a different way to think about this issue. You're saying that resource A cannot be created if resource B does not exist.

A common status code for this is `409 Conflict`. Conflict suggests that while the request itself is valid, the state of another resource prevents it from being successful. If the state of the other resources changes (you create the student resource) the initial request will work.